# Enter any mathematical expression on the textbox and click the button, the result of th expression will be shown in alert window. in reactjs eg2+3-1

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
function MyForm() {
const [name, setName] = useState("");
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
var a=parseInt(name)
console.log(a)
alert(name);//need to alert message evaluate the mathematical expressions 
console.log(name)
}
return (
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
<label>Enter your name:
<input 
type="text" 
value={name}
onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
/>
</label>
<input type="submit" />
</form>
)
}
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<MyForm/>);
```

> in this code i need to pass the input value to the function and evaluate or do mathematical expression by result showing to the alert box

Comment: by manually writing simple expression ,the alert  message evaluating the expressions but i can't pass the input value by the alert function didnt getting any answer it only showing the string values

Comment: I'd suggest you to review your needs and organize the code. It seems you want a solution for a given exercise and if that's true that's not the concept of Stackoverflow. About the code, there are some wrong react concepts in what I can see like the `a=parseInt` etc.. so It seems to me you might need to try to at least start the implementation of your logic and if you feel stuck you come with the question.

Comment: simply what can i do in this code ??

Comment: Well, if I can help you shortly... you would probably need to implement kinda a regex to extract the operators, create some validations to ensure you have a real math expression and go ahead with that. But just remember, the Stackoverflow context is not for "make the code for you" in case you understood that. Anyways, good luck.

Comment: This is a test question. This forum is not for helping folks with their homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

function MyForm() {
const [name, setName,] = useState("");

function handleClick(){
var y=addbits("h");
console.log("this is the value passed from addbits",h)
alert(h)
}



function addbits(name) {

var total = 0;
    name = name.match(/[+\-]*(\.\d+|\d+(\.\d+)?)/g) || [];
    
while (name.length) {
  total += parseFloat(name.shift());
}
 return total; 
}

var h=addbits(name)


console.log(h)

return (
<div>
  <h1>Hit the click Button :::</h1>
<form >
  <label>Enter your name:
    <input 
      type="text" 
      value={name}
      onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
    />
  </label>
  
 </form>
<button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
</div>
)
} 

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(<MyForm />);
```